# Apply Changes To Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm using MVC and entity Framework to save data through repositories.

Usually the View Model, and the entityDB model is slightly different, so I have things like this in the repository. Is there a better way?

```
private void ApplyChangesToModel(AttributeImportModel entity, AttributeImport dbDef)
    {
        dbDef.ApplicationID = entity.ApplicationID;
        dbDef.Canceled = entity.Canceled;
        dbDef.DateRequested = entity.DateRequested;
        dbDef.Processed = entity.Processed;
        dbDef.ScheduleID = entity.ScheduleID;
        //dbDef.UniqueID = entity.UniqueID;
        dbDef.UserID = entity.UserID;
        dbDef.UserIP = entity.UserIP;
    }

    private void ApplyChangesToModel(AttributeImport dbDef, AttributeImportModel entity)
    {
        entity.AttributeImportID = dbDef.AttributeImportID;
        entity.ApplicationID = dbDef.ApplicationID;
        entity.Canceled = dbDef.Canceled;
        entity.DateRequested = dbDef.DateRequested;
        entity.Processed = dbDef.Processed;
        entity.ScheduleID = dbDef.ScheduleID;
        //dbDef.UniqueID = entity.UniqueID;
        entity.UserID = dbDef.UserID;
        entity.UserIP = dbDef.UserIP;
    }

    private void ApplyChangesToModel(AttributeImportModel dbDef, AttributeImportModel entity)
    {
        entity.AttributeImportID = dbDef.AttributeImportID;
        entity.ApplicationID = dbDef.ApplicationID;
        entity.Canceled = dbDef.Canceled;
        entity.DateRequested = dbDef.DateRequested;
        entity.Processed = dbDef.Processed;
        entity.ScheduleID = dbDef.ScheduleID;
        //dbDef.UniqueID = entity.UniqueID;
        entity.UserID = dbDef.UserID;
        entity.UserIP = dbDef.UserIP;
    }
```

Comment: This is what AutoMapper is made for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using AutoMapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AttributeImportModel, AttributeImport>();
Mapper.Map(dbdef, entity); //Mapper.Map(source, target)
```